# Why doesn't Scala have a sensible equality defined between anonymous types?

Tags: c#, class, scala, equals, anonymous-types

Consider this code:

```
val a = new { val x = 1; val y = 2 }
val b = new { val x = 1; val y = 2 }

a == b // false
```

Wouldn't it be sensible if anonymous classes would have some equality defined which would return true, if fields/methods/values are the same?

I imagine that this could also reduce the number of class files Scala has to generate in certain use cases.

(As far as I know C# uses the same class for anonymous types if they have the same values *in the same order* and returns `true` when those get compared to each other.)

Comment: this is a complaint, not a question

Comment: I can't see how this is a complaint. There is a huge amount of question which use the "Why does/Why doesn't" pattern on SO. Of course if people came out of their hiding instead of voting "close" they could actually tell what they dislike about it and I could improve the wording.

Comment: Have you considered asking the Scala guys?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it's difficult to do the right thing in all cases.

Generally, in OO languages, equality is only meaningful between instances of the same class. When you're using anonymous classes the way you do in the question, you actually have two different classes which happen to look the same.

Consider (in pseudocode):

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
}

class Dimensions {
    int x;
    int y;
}

class Rectangle {
    Point lowerLeftCorner;
    Dimensions dimensions;   
}
```

Here a Point should never compare equal to a Dimensions, even if they have the same x and y value. But two Points with the same x and y values should compare equal.

In your example, how is the language to magically know if you intended the two different anonymous classes to have the same meaning or not? They could conceptually be two Points, or a Point and a Dimensions.

(I disagree that C#'s system is better: first, it doesn't know that your anonymous classes were intended to be comparable; and second, i really don't see why order should affect things. In all other cases, the order of the fields of a class doesn't matter; why should it matter here?)

Comment: @soc: yes, anonymous classes can be considered to have the same name. My point is that it's not necessarily the right thing to do. "how is the language to magically know if you intended the two different anonymous classes to have the same meaning or not?"

Comment: @soc: equality cannot be easily defined by the language, because the language doesn't know the programmer's intentions. There are all sorts of examples of this -- two objects with different values in fields can compare the same (if one field is a transient value such as a cache); two objects with the same values in fields can compare different (particularly for mutable objects); equality is generally contingent on the semantic meaning of the object, which the programming language just doesn't know.

Comment: I didn't claim that C# was better, I just wanted to point out that some other language took a different approach. In your answer you say that equality requires the same "class name" (slightly simplified) and the values. Can't anonymous classes be considered to have all the same "no class name", so that the only thing matters are the structure and the values?

Comment: Under which circumstances would you consider `new { val x = 1 }` to be different from `new { val x = 1 }` and why would one be acceptable (e. g. as an argument) and not the other?

Comment: Well, if you are using anonymous classes then you explicitly don't care about the type, do you? So the C# approach is as good as any. If you care about the exact type then you make class - otherwise you don't. Btw: Anonymous types are equal when all their public properties have the same values. The order does not matter. One of the advantages is that you can use them in Linq when you only need some adhoc intermediate type and filter out duplicates.

Comment: Order does matter: `Within the same program, two anonymous object initializers that specify a sequence of properties of the same names and compile-time types in the same order will produce instances of the same anonymous type.` (§7.6.10.6)